# Getting pdf data from cloudinary and saving it in flutter

Tags: flutter, cloudinary

I have been using cloudinary to store my pdf files the use firebase as my backend. However, am having this issue with it. When I use http.get on the link provided by cloudinary `https://res.cloudinary.com/cloudname/raw/upload/vxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` I get ascii data instead of the pdf file. I have tried to write the data as string to a file with .pdf extension that has not worked. I have tried to convert it to bytes then write to the file as bytes and that has not worked either. Any help on how I can save this file on android using flutter It would be a great help.

```
    await http.post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${DotEnv().env['cloud_name']}/raw/upload',body: { "file": "data:raw/pdf;base64,$pdf", "upload_preset": DotEnv().env['upload_preset']} );
    var response = await http.get('https://res.cloudinary.com/<cloudname>/raw/upload/v1590958359/gsvxe4zp7bb6yyldrccu');
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path2 = directory.path;

    File x = File('$path2/trial.pdf');
    x.writeAsString(response.body);
```

Here is the code as I currently have it. pdf in this case is the base64 encoding of the pdf. The link I have here in `http.get` is from a file I had already uploaded.

Comment: can you share the code presenting how you are trying to achieve this right now ?

Comment: Could you please share an example URL to a PDF that we can look at?

Comment: @TolgaKartal  I have updated it with the code.

Comment: @AleksandarKostadinov I have updated it with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the additional details.

Firstly, I would recommend you change the `resource_type` from `raw` to `image`. In addition, please update the MIME type in your Base64 Data URI to `application/pdf`.

The URL you then get from Cloudinary upon a successful upload will be to a PDF resource which means you can download it with a simple cURL request or via any HTTP library.

For example, using the `secure_url` to the asset returned in the Upload API Response to download the file to `my_test_file.pdf` -

```
curl -s https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/multi_page_pdf.pdf --output my_test_file.pdf
```